# Active Directory Certificate Services Code signing Subject Empty

Tags: active-directory, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I'm contracted by a branch of a large multinational company to write some in-house software. I'm trying to push this software out to users using ClickOnce. To sign the application, I was issued a code signing certificate that was created with their AD CS server (requested by creating a CSR in mmc.exe and uploading it to the server's web portal). Everything seemed to work fine, but after publishing I keep getting an error stating "Publisher cannot be verified".

After some investigation, I suspect this error is due to the "Subject" field of my certificate being empty. The admin has assured me that they've used the 'out of the box' code signing template from Microsoft to create the certificate. I've tried requesting the certificate again, manually filling in the fields in the Subject tab of the properties menu, but the finished certificate still has no subject filled in. I have a full AD account on the network with regular user permissions.

Does anyone have any idea what we're doing wrong?

Comment: don't know what you are doing wrong, but, as it gives you feedback looks like Kerberos isn't happy. Problem with that would be, that when you as your account generating TGT and TGP are assigned to you (not to service - or other user).

Comment: @Michal the CSR that I created was uploaded to the AD CS web portal. From there, an admin had to approve it before a certificate was issued by the server. I'd think that would mean it's properly signed and trusted by the CA

Comment: ok, now full story looks good. If that's only assumption that, this certificate is used by application which was issued by CS then shouldn't be really problem. (it is still worth it to check if that one which you have right one would be manually recognised by it's issuer - upload and verify manually). Unless there's second option. Application has certificate but you are trying to get two levels of verification (application + user) then it's different story and you will require two separated keys (and key == which btw for user works by default for only 15min-up to an hour). then recreate by CS.